# Android Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created custom listview which contain Imageview+TextView+Checkbox 
Now  my problem is that i have to get which row's check box is checked.

Xml row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="60dip">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_width="260dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/desc" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip" android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="Text" android:textSize="20dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:textColor="@color/black" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Phone number"
            android:id="@+id/phone_no" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="60dip">

        <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chk_number"></CheckBox>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and Adapter is:

```
class ContactList extends ArrayAdapter{

    Activity context;
    public ContactList(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row,names);
        this.context = context;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    TextView Name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    TextView Number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
    Name.setText(names.get(position));
    Number.setText(numbers.get(position));

    CheckBox checkboxnumberScramble = (CheckBox) row.findViewWithTag(R.id.chk_number);
    checkboxnumberScramble.setChecked(true);
    checkboxnumberScramble.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) { 
                setCheckboxflag(true);
            }else{
                setCheckboxflag(false);
            }
         }
    });

    return (row);
    }
}
```

I get exception on onCreate of my Activity .

Comment: What's the exception (paste from your 'adb logcat')?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `OnItemClickListner` interface to check which list item is selected.

like:

```
class youractivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickLister
```

and set the listener to your listview

```
listview_object.setOnItemClicklistener(this);
```

override the `OnItemClick` method like:

```
@Override
OnItemClick(){
  //what you want to do? that is here
}
```

thats all.

Answer (score 0):

**checked getview() and in this checked if statement written below**

I thinked that it is something wrong in if statement

```
     if (isChecked) //--> (isChecked) not contain the Checkbox name
     { 
        setCheckboxflag(true);
     }
     else
     {
        setCheckboxflag(false);
     }
```

you used

```
 if (checkBoxName.isChecked) //--> it contain checkBoxName
 { 
    setCheckboxflag(true);
 }
 else
 {
    setCheckboxflag(false);
 }
```

Comment: But he is using the argument to the method `onCheckedChanged`, which should work as well.  But I would have coded it `setCheckboxflag(isChecked);` why use an if statement to set a boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
CheckBox checkboxnumberScramble = (CheckBox)row.findViewWithTag(R.id.chk_number);
```

causing you NPE.

You are not setting tag but you are trying to retrieve it.

Otherwise simply use

```
CheckBox checkboxnumberScramble = (CheckBox)row.findViewWithId(R.id.chk_number);
```

to find it view.

If you want use the `findViewWithTag()` method, then first have to  set the tag with `checkboxnumberScramble.setTag(tag)` so you later can retrieve it.